# How to preserve validation list's from another sheet when copying them to a new book

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master worksheet filled with data with many cells confined to a list with Data validation.
The lists reference in the Data validation criteria are on a separate sheet called "Lists"

My code creates a new sheet and populates it with a range from the Master sheet. I have the formatting and validation preserved perfectly in the copy.

My problem is when I try to copy the "List" sheet to a new workbook, and move the New Sheet to this workbook: I lose all of my data validation.

This is how I'm trying to do the copy:

```
    MasterBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks.Add
    NewBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(MasterBook).Sheets("Lists").Copy after:=Workbooks(NewBook).Sheets(Workbooks(NewBook).Worksheets.Count)
    Workbooks(MasterBook).Sheets(SheetName).Move after:=Workbooks(NewBook).Sheets(Workbooks(NewBook).Worksheets.Count)
```

I can't even do this outside VBA. I tried copy/pastespecial xlpastevalidation but it doesn't work. I'm hoping I don't have to recreate the validation rules in the copy because there are about 50 in each row.

Is there a way to preserve the relationship in the copy/move or to copy/paste it from the Master Workbook to the new one?

Comment: If you do not create a similar list to "Data validation criteria" from existing "Lists" worksheet, how to keep validation without an existing reference? Is the "Data validation criteria" a named range? If yes, you should copy the range and then create such a name for selection resulting after copying. Only after that you must copy the validation.

Comment: You might find it easier to use `SaveCopyAs` to create a copy of your workbook, then open that copy and delete anything which is not needed.

Comment: Tim Williams: I like the idea but I'm concerned about the complexities of handling the file save location. Is there a way to copy a workbook without saving?

Comment: FaneDuru: The list is not a named range. The dialog points to the list like this: Allow: 'List', Source: '=Lists!$E$4:$E$9', In-Cell dropdown = checked. I don't understand your suggestion - sorry.

Comment: You could try copying both sheets at the same time: `Workbooks(MasterBook).Sheets(Array("Lists", SheetName)).Copy after:=Workbooks(NewBook).Sheets(Workbooks(NewBook).Worksheets.Count)`

Comment: Tim Williams: Was super excited for a second but unfortunately Array does the same thing: the validation is lost. Saved me a line of code though!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this? Seems like a gap in Excel's capabilities that I can't programmatically preserve a link (validation list) between two sheets when copying/moving them to another book.